# React for displaying the log file in real-time (Flask backend)

Tags: reactjs, flask, real-time

I have a working code (Flask + plain JS) which shows the growing log file in real time.
I have a problem converting it to ReactJS.

app.py (Flask, working code, no problems)

```
@app.route('/stream')
def stream():
    def generate():
        fname="/Users/xxx/tmp/log.txt"
        with open(fname) as f:
            while True:
                yield f.read()
                sleep(1)
    return 
    app.response_class(generate(), mimetype='text/plain')

app.run()
```

index.html (plain JS, no problems)

```
<pre id="output"></pre>
<script>
    var output = document.getElementById('output');
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('GET', '');
    xhr.send();

    setInterval(function() {
        output.textContent = xhr.responseText;
    }, 1000);
</script>
```

Below is my attempt to convert it to React.

On MyPage.jsx I put the button "Show Real Time Log". 
When user clicks this button the Modal Dialog should pop-up and display the log.

File: MyPage.jsx

```
import Modal from 'react-bootstrap/Modal'
import { Button } from 'react-bootstrap'

const showLog = (e) => {
    render(<ModalLog />,  document.getElementById('output'));
}

const MyPage = () => {
  return (
    <div>
          <div id="output"></div>
          <button type="button" onClick={showLog}>Show Real Time Log</button>
</div
}

function ModalLog() {
  const [show, setShow] = useState(true);

  const handleClose = () => setShow(false);
  const handleShow = () => setShow(true);

  return (
    <>
      <Modal show={show} onHide={handleClose}>
        <Modal.Header closeButton>
          <Modal.Title>Real Time Log</Modal.Title>
        </Modal.Header>
        <Modal.Body> Log file live update goes here </Modal.Body>
        <Modal.Footer>
          <Button variant="primary" onClick={handleClose}>
            Close
          </Button>
        </Modal.Footer>
      </Modal>
    </>
  );
}
```

Questions:

1. Where to put into MyPage.jsx the JS code currently sitting in my index.html?
2. When I press the button "Show Real Time Log" the Modal is displayed only 1st time, after I close it never displayed again. I understand what it is because handleClose() was called, but how to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**(1) Where to put into MyPage.jsx the JS code currently sitting in my index.html?**

Simple answer is you don't. It's directly manipulating the DOM and this is a severe react anti-pattern. You would convert it to an `useEffect` hook to fetch the latest log data and save it to component state, to be rendered.

```
const [logs, setLogs] = useState('');
useEffect(() => {
  // asynchronous function to fetch logs
  const fetchLogs = async () => {
    try {
      const logResponse = await /* logic to fetch log */
      setLogs(logResponse);
    } catch {
      // just don't update state, or set an error message in state,
      // basically anything you want to do to handle errors
    }
  }

  // setup interval to fetch logs
  const intervalTimer = setInterval(fetchLogs, 1000);

  // function to clean up effect when component unmounts
  return () => clearInterval(intervalTimer);
}, []); // empty dependency array to run when mounted
```

**(2) When I press the button "Show Real Time Log" the Modal is displayed only 1st time, after I close it never displayed again. I understand what it is because handleClose() was called, but how to fix it?**

You initial state to display the modal is `true`. I would refactor the logic a bit to have `MyPage` hold the state if the modal is open or not (instead of the modal). Pass `show` and `handleClose` as props to `ModalLog`. No need to render the modal into another DOM element, I believe the react-bootstrap will handle creating a portal for you. You can simply render it into your component.

```
const MyPage = () => {
  const [show, setShow] = useState(false);

  const handleClose = () => setShow(false);
  const handleShow = () => setShow(true);

  return (
    <div>
      <div id="output"></div>
      <button type="button" onClick={handleShow}>Show Real Time Log</button>
      <ModalLog show={show} onHide={handleClose} />
    </div>
  );
}

function ModalLog({ show, onHide }) {
  return (
    <>
      <Modal show={show} onHide={onHide}>
        <Modal.Header closeButton>
          <Modal.Title>Real Time Log</Modal.Title>
        </Modal.Header>
        <Modal.Body> Log file live update goes here </Modal.Body>
        <Modal.Footer>
          <Button variant="primary" onClick={handleClose}>
            Close
          </Button>
        </Modal.Footer>
      </Modal>
    </>
  );
}
```

**Suggestion**: Place the log state and logic to fetch and display the logs *in the modal* as it appears you only care to display them when the modal is open and there's no point in fetching them in the background while the modal is closed.